# Understanding Operators of Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

```
String query = "START n1=node:TEST_INDEX(nodeName='" + elementID
                + "') match n1-[:hasSubClass]->n2-[:hasPropertyGroup]->n3-[:containsProperty]->n4 with n2 match n2-[:hasInstance]->n5 "
                + "where n2.elementType='class' and not(n4.status! = 'Deleted') and n4.nodeName! =~ '(?i)" + propertyName + "' and where count(n5)=0 return n4,count(n5)";
```

I am trying to convert this particular query to MATCH query facing issue in understanding these conditions

> not(n4.status! = 'Deleted') and n4.nodeName! =~ '(?i)" + propertyName
>   + "'

I tried to change the query :-

```
MATCH(n1:TESTDATA{nodeName:'ProductConcept'})
match (n1)-[:hasSubClass]->(n2)-[:hasPropertyGroup]->(n3)-[:containsProperty]->(n4) with n2,n4
match (n2)-[:hasInstance]->(n5)
where n2.elementType='class' 
and NOT EXISTS(n4.status) 
and n4.nodeName <>'(?i)view'
//and where count(n5)=0 
return n4,count(n5)
```

Comment: What is the `!` doing in there? I don't believe that symbol is allowed within a property name or a variable name.

Comment: Thats why i am unable to understand how to convert the query

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you pass `elementId` and `propertyName` as [parameters](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/), this Cypher seems to be equivalent to the intent of your original query:

```
START n1=node:TEST_INDEX(nodeName=$elementId)
MATCH (n1)-[:hasSubClass]->(n2)-[:hasPropertyGroup]->()-[:containsProperty]->(n4)
WHERE
  n2.elementType = 'class' AND
  n4.status = 'Deleted' AND
  (NOT n4.nodeName =~ ('(?i)' + $propertyName)) AND
  SIZE((n2)-[:hasInstance]->()) = 0
RETURN n4
```

This query does not bother to return the equivalent of `COUNT(n5)`, since the query requires that the value must always be 0.